# Teleport Command in minecraft ps4

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm attempting to run a repeat command that will move an armour stand 1 block on the x axis, but when I put

```
/tp @e[type=armor_stand] ~1 ~ ~
```

it does not move it 1 block from the entity, but instead moves it 1 block from where the command is executed. So seems that ~ functions differently on PS4 than on PC.

Is there a way to remedy this on PS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as running a `/tp` command from a command block teleports relative to the command block, you’ll need to execute the command relative to the armour stand.

***How to: run a command relative to the armour stand.***

Using this command, we can execute a command from the position of the armour stand as if it became the command block.
`/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~~~ tp @e[type=armor_stand] ~1~~`

Hope this helped!